# "composite" of two webflux requests / add header attribute that is a Mono<String>

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

I'm kind of at a lost with the following problem:
I have to offer a service that can be called by any user. internally, I build a new request from the original request and send it to another service on behalf of the "system". The inner service is secured with oauth2.

Now I have to get a accessToken internally for the system user and attach this as a header attribute to the inner request.

But the token is a mono and the header attribute must be a string.
Do I think it is too complicated? How can I send a request in a resource server with a system user that is not the user of the current session/request?

Comment: Can't you `.flatMap()` the token mono and set the header in the callback, returning the webclient response?

Comment: I had to do the same thing too. It's easier to use something at a lower level. The webflux requests are more for consuming an API. For manipulating the entire request/response, it was easier to just use something like OkHttp for me.

Comment: Thanks @adam-bickford! I'll post the sample code as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public Mono<String> createTask(...) {
    Mono<String> location = accessTokenRequestKeycloak.getTokenNonBlocking(...)  
    .flatMap(token -> {  
            Mono<String> locationHeader = postActivity(...);
        return locationHeader;
      });  
    location.subscribe(activityId->log.debug("task {} created",   activityId.toString()));  
    return location;  
    }
```

Comment: Be careful subscribing twice like that, if it's a cold publisher you could fire off multiple requests, etc. Also, the caller may never actually subscribe to it but your logging will make it look like they did. For side effects like logging you likely want a `.doOnNext()`.